# Object somehow reversed in position

Tags: objects, mirror

I'm not sure how this happened, but my object appears to have been reversed completely in it's direction.  I tried using mirror (both the modifier and transform tool) and all it does is revert back to its current position.  Any idea why this has happened?  It's like the object has somehow been mirrored but I can't make it face the right direction.

This is how it's currently facing:

[image]

As you can see from this picture, it's reversed somehow from the reference photo:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you say (not much clear imho) your "mechanical" model has a front part, roughly shaped like a "b" letter, that in the reference is roughly shaped like a "d" letter - thus "reversed" on X axis.

but if you try to mirror on X on your model, after confirming the command it gets reverted, as you say. This is weird, and it happens because your model is set as rigid body - active (dynamic), and a Z180 rotation, imho.

Something like this:

[image]

Try

1. removing rigid body
2. mirror the model on X - it should now stay mirrored
3. apply "rotation&scale"
4. check normals
5. if you need it, now set rigid body again

something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes it was definitely the rigid body and lack of rotation and scale.  After removing the rigid body and following your steps (normals definitely had to be recalculated) it worked.  This is a good lesson in remembering to create my object in scale!

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror your object along its pivot point by pressing <kbd>,</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and in this case pressing <kbd>X</kbd> to mirror along X axis.

It appears that the problem was due to a rigidbody on the piece interfering with transform operations.

Your rotation and scale are unapplied, be aware that modelling on a non uniformly scaled object will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response!  However, I tried to apply rotation and scale, but it made my object look deformed and mirroring didn't do anything.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: are you using a 2.8 branch?

I had some problems with transforms in 2.8, I did check your file beforehand and found nothing strange, I just double checked and everything is in order, your rigidbody settings seem to interfere with applying transforms, even tough it didn't prevent me from mirroring it might be related in your case. Try disabling the rigidbody on the piece before attempting to mirror.

Comment: @Firewill in the above screenshot version 2.78 is visible...

Comment: Yeah I'm using the latest version of the fracture modifier build.  But it looks like it was the rigid body that was the issue.  Once I turned that off and applied the mirror, it worked.  Thanks again!!